# What is the maximum allowable size for a declaration on the stack?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, stack, runtime-error

i am using visual studio 2010.

i have a three dimensional structure array which, i think, gives me the wrong error.
The array is defined from

```
#define BUCKETS 2048
#define B_ENTRIES 4096

typedef struct fpinfo
{
    unsigned long long offset;
    unsigned long length;
     char fing_print[33];
}fpinfo;
```

as

```
struct fpinfo search_buf[TNK_CACHE_SIZE][BUCKETS][B_ENTRIES];
```

The problem is,

when i define **TNK_CACHE_SIZE** to 6 it does not give me compile time error but have access violation error at run time when i try to write in to it.

on the other hand, if i define **TNK_CACHE_SIZE** to 3 it does give me the following compile time error.

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1248: image size (86CB7000) exceeds maximum
>   allowable size (80000000)

1) Why does it ignore the first declaration at compile time while it does not for the second one, when it was just half of the first one.

2) What is the maximum allowable size for a declaration on the stack?

3)Does this allowable size include all the other memory allocations in the project or is it one memory allocation after the other until there is ***no more allocable memory space*** and the last one not been able to be allocated flagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler and linker's check on the image size is probably imperfect. If you make it too big, probably some calculation has wrapped around resulting in an incorrect result which appears to be in the valid image size range. I.e. your toolchain will catch a small error in an image size going too big, but not a large error.

Note that if you double the number `86CB,7000`, you get one that requires more than 32 bits to represent, namely `1,0D96,E000`. If the calculation is done in 32 bits, this might get chopped to `D96,E000`, making the image size look in range, though totally wrong.

Try dynamically allocating the space with `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to allocate such big object on the stack but you can override default stack size for MSVC in two ways:

- Use the `/F` option (in the **Project Properties** go in the **C/C++** section then **Command Line** and write /F:*bytes* in the **Additional Options** field. Anyway this is not a good idea because it works only for one step compiling and linking.
- In the **Project Properties** go in the **Linker** section then **System** and write the size you need in the **Stack Reserve Size** field.

Comment: Here's microsoft link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that this array should not be declared on the stack.

A tyical stack size in Windows is 2Mb per thread.  Note that is *per thread*, so even if you could make the stack that large, your system would likley grind to a halt.  I am not even sure that virtual memory disk swapping is supported for stack data, but your code would run very slow if it did.

Static or dynamic allocation would be more appropriate, but even then that is a heavy load for most systems, especially 32bit systems.  It may be more efficient to use a memory mapped file.  This works in the same way as disk swapping, but you are explicitly requesting it rather than letting the OS memory manger make that decision non-deterministically.

Answer (score 0):

3 * 2048 * 4096 * sizeof (pinfo) amounts to well over a gigabyte.  That's just for your table, so yeah, your image is going to be ginormous, and is obviously larger than what VS will allow by default.

You'd be better off allocating that memory dynamically.

```
/**
 * Allocate memory in a single contiguous block.  Be sure to free it
 * when you don't need it anymore.
 */
fpinfo *search_buf_store = malloc(sizeof *search_buf_store * 
                                  TNK_CACHE_SIZE * 
                                  BUCKETS * 
                                  B_ENTRIES);

/**
 * Declare search_buf as a pointer to a 2-d array, and set it to point
 * to the block we just allocated.  You can then index search_buf
 * as you would a regular 3-D array.  Just be sure that if you pass search_buf
 * to any functions, you declare it in the parameter list just like it's 
 * declared here.
 */
fpinfo (*search_buf)[BUCKETS][B_ENTRIES] = 
  (fpinfo (*)[BUCKETS][B_ENTRIES]) search_buf_store;
```